# Decreasing font size dynamically in relative containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So we have a slider .outer which scales height by the width of viewport and example slide li .inner, what has some text in it. Now when we decrease the window width the slide li .inner will not fit in the .outer, thus parts of text getting hidden.

What I wanted to do was to add a font-size: x% to slide .inner whenever window is resized and .inners height is greater than .outer. So by 5% for example it would go down by intervals 95%, 90% 85% until .inner slide would smaller height than slider .outer .

unworking example: https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/JOQQWY?editors=1111

```
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
  var inn = $('.inner');
  var inner = $('.inner').outerHeight();
  var outer = $('.outer').outerHeight();
  if (inner > outer) {
      var i;
      for (i = 100; i > 50;i--){
      inn.css('font-size', i+'%' )
      i--;
      }
 }
console.log('outer ' + outer);
console.log('inner ' + inner);
});
```

I was hoping somehow using for loop to decrease font-size percent on resize but im not sure even if can be done like this.

Comment: Why don't you use vw as a font-size unity or media queries or a combination of both?

Comment: @JonasGiuro Not feasible, it will get small to the point you can't view the text.

Comment: @Highdef you could use media queries to correct that for every breakpoint

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet But that will just make the font-size jump and you will have to try every possible combination so it doesn't look odd during resize.

Comment: @JonasGiuro Im sure you can resolve most if it like that, but assume some really lengthy text blocks or something vs mostly short ones.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `$(inn).css('font-size', i+'%' );` ?

Comment: Is it necessary you have to scale it by height and not width?

Comment: Why you don't use rem units and font-size % in the html tag? Your solution seems overkill

Comment: MasterYoda seems to work both ways.
@Highdef not sure how would using width in this context matter, seeing as width is same anyway for the slider and slide.

Comment: Try this   $(".inner").css("font-size") * i;

Comment: for (i = 20; i > 10;i=i-3){
      inn.css('font-size', i+'px' ); But this just scales down the size and you have to wrie the condition to scale it back up.

Comment: You should change  if (inner>outer) to   if (inner<outer)

Comment: @Highdef reason I dont want use px is because there might be different sized text blocks in there, I want it to scale.

Comment: I really think that this should be achieved with only CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).on("load resize", function() {
      var inn = $(".inner");
      var inner = $(".inner").outerHeight();
      var outer = $(".outer").outerHeight();
      if (inner<outer) {
        //while (inner > outer) {
        var i;
        for (i = 100; i > 50; i--) {
          $(".inner").css("font-size",i+'%');
          i--;
        }
      }
      // }
      //inn.css('font-size', '70%');

      console.log("outer " + outer);
      console.log("inner " + inner);
    });
```

Comment: I had  var inn is  = $(".inner"); already. And why switch (inner>outer) you just reverse it. The point was once .inner has height greater than .outer , it would decrement fontsize froom 100% by 5% so 95%, 90% 80% until .inner height is smaller than .outer so the text block would fit nicely on different widths.

Comment: Because the condition will not be true. Moreover, you can use the var inn
inn.css("font-size",i+'%');